# What does require('electron') return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am learning Electron. I can't find some good explanation on this question. I see it appearing in many basic Electron examples, such as:

```
const { app, Tray } = require('electron')
```

What exactly does `require('electron')` return to be destructured here?

Update: clarifying my question. So, after reading about Node.js, I understand that `require()` is used to load module. Upon loading the module (in this case, `electron`), `require()` returns an `exports` object. This object could have a list of methods or sub-objects within it. Here, `app` and `Tray` are among those sub-objects. My question is that I could not locate in Electron documentation describing the entire list of these objects. If anyone could point to where to read up, thanks very much.

Comment: Download a good IDE and ctrl+click on `'electron'`. It should take you to the source where you can see what it actually exports. You can also `console.dir` it to see what's inside. It all should be documented somewhere on their website too: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#electron-api

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api